# Passing values from javascript to code behind in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a variable in `aspx.cs` when I click the Datagrid particular row;
Then from the javascript, I should get that value and pass into aspx.cs variable.

how to do this?

Comment: what exactly you want to do, provide some code, what exactly you want to do with that variable at server side?

Comment: There are many ways to do this however if you tell the purpose someone might advise you an alternate easier method.

Answer (score 13):

### Using html controls

First you use a hidden input control as:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="SendA" name="SendA" />
```

Second you add to that control the value you like to send on code behind using javascript as:

```
document.getElementById("SendA").value = "1";
```

And then on post back you get that value as:

```
Request.Form["SendA"]
```

### Using asp.net Controls

The same way if you use asp.net control can be as:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="SendA" Value="" />
<script>
   document.getElementById("<%=SendA.ClientID%>").value = "1";
</script>
```

and get it on code behind with `SendA.Value;`

And of course you can use ajax calls to send on code behind values, or simple call url with url parameters that return no content.

Comment: finally, so simple. Adding "<%=...%>" did the trick. thanks a lot Aristos.

Comment: one thing I'd like to add is that if you're not seeing an updated value from the hiddenField, try creating a button to trigger a new event and you will see the value update(as opposed to relying on the pageLoad function event)