# Pass javascript var to asp.net code behind (c#)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a problem, I want to pass javascript var to server side.

I want to pass the value of var `autocomplete` to string named `Event_Address`;

aspx.cs:

```
protected void ButtonAddEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Event_Address =hdnfldVariable.Value;
}
```

aspx:

```
var autocomplete;

<script type="text/javascript">
    var somefunction = function() {
        var hdnfldVariable = document.getElementById('hdnfldVariable');
        hdnfldVariable.value = autocomplete;
    }
</script>

<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnfldVariable" runat="server" />

<asp:Button ID="ButtonAddEvent" runat="server" Text="הוסף אירוע חדש" 
        Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Gisha" Font-Size="17pt" ForeColor="Blue" 
        onclick="ButtonAddEvent_Click" 
        style="z-index: 1; left: 497px; top: 774px; position: absolute" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Is you code is working?

Comment: Use `var hdnfldVariable = document.getElementById("<%= hdnfldVariable.ClientID %>")` if the hidden field ClientID is dynamic one.

Comment: thank for your answer , my code working , i tried to pass address input that powerd by script of google maps, so i think my code is dynamic.

Comment: take a look here https://forums.asp.net/t/1211504.aspx?Passing+values+from+Javascript+to+ASPX

Comment: If you are using a master page then  document.getElementById('<%= hdnfldVariable.ClientID%>').value = autocomplete; It should then be visible in code behind.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to teo van kot's answer, if the `ClientID` for `HiddenField` is a dynamic one, it should be defined as dynamic `ClientID` like this:

```
var autocomplete = "[somevalue]";

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var somefunction = function() {
        // set this if you have dynamic ClientID
        var hdnfldVariable = document.getElementById("<%= hdnfldVariable.ClientID %>");
        hdnfldVariable.value = autocomplete;
    }
    </script>

      <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnfldVariable" runat="server" />

       <asp:Button ID="ButtonAddEvent" runat="server" Text="הוסף אירוע חדש" 
        Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Gisha" Font-Size="17pt" ForeColor="Blue" 
        onclick="ButtonAddEvent_Click"
    OnClientClick="somefunction();"
        style="z-index: 1; left: 497px; top: 774px; position: absolute" />
</asp:Content>
```

Reference:

[Passing values from javascript to code behind in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603256/passing-values-from-javascript-to-code-behind-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call your js function on Button click you shold add it to `OnClientClick` attribute. like this:

```
var autocomplete;

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var somefunction = function() {
        var hdnfldVariable = document.getElementById('hdnfldVariable');
        hdnfldVariable.value = autocomplete;
    }
    </script>

      <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnfldVariable" runat="server" />

       <asp:Button ID="ButtonAddEvent" runat="server" Text="הוסף אירוע חדש" 
        Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Gisha" Font-Size="17pt" ForeColor="Blue" 
        onclick="ButtonAddEvent_Click" 
        OnClientClick="somefunction();"
        style="z-index: 1; left: 497px; top: 774px; position: absolute" />
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can save the value of your "autocomplete" to hidden field or you can use ajax method to call a c# function , to pass the value from front-end to back end.

or in your case use the attrbute property to change the value .

please refer this link for the ajax call
[Ajax method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508409/ajax-method-call)

Comment: how can i use ajax? can you please typed it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[Web Method]` in server side. You should add `using System.Web.Services;` to your cs code for using web methods. Here is the steps:

- Change your button; use html button instead of server side button.
- Create js function and call it with onclick event in button.
- Pass your variable with `PageMethods.YourWebMethod(yourParam);` in js.
- Then you have it in server side web method.
  Here is an ex for you:

  ```
   function JsFunctionOnclick(){ 
    PageMethods.MyPageMethod(myParameter);
   }
  ```

  and this is server side:

  ```
  [WebMethod]
  public static void MyPageMethod(string param)
  {
      //do something
  }
  ```

Be sure your web method is **static** Good luck.